# Why is the error between the desired signal and estimated signal in the case of LMS filter remaining constant even after n number of iterations

Tags: adaptive-filters, system-identification, noise-cancellation, lms, white-noise

[image][image: Image shows the matlab code of lms algorithm.][image]

I am giving white noise as input to an adaptive filter which is initialized to zero (value of filter coefficients of adaptive filter is 0). I am getting a desired response $d(n)$  by passing white noise through an unknown channel of impulse response $h(n)$.

Now using LMS algorithm, I am trying to update the adaptive filter coefficients by using the equation
$$w(n+1)=w(n)+\mu u(n) e(n)$$ 
where $\mu$ is the step size or adaptation speed of the algorithm, $u(n)$ is the white noise which is passed to a speaker and $e(n)$ is the difference between desired response and estimated response.

Even after $n$ number of iterations, why is that the error signal, which is the difference between desired response and estimated response, not decreasing but remaining almost constant.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can tell the values of mu, and make sure you are using the same u[n] sequence for input to adaptive filter as well as to the speaker. If not then the error will not converge. Even better, if you could post the block diagram of your setup. This way it would also help improve your understanding (a picture is worth 1000 words..)

Comment: The value of mu is changed from 0.01 to 0.1.Still, there is no change in the error signal

Comment: There seems to be delay from speaker input till computation of d[n] which is not taken into account. Instead of white noise, can you try giving a known signal, say, all 1s (constant amplitude signal) as a sanity check?

Comment: Are you sure that the model of the adaptive filter matches the order of the unknown filter characterized by $h(n)$?

Comment: @jithinrj The response that I am getting is that there is always one sample delay between the desired signal and the signal estimated by the adaptive filter, i.e the adaptive filter is producing the estimate of the desired sample after 1 sample delay.Won't the adaptive filter able to adapt to the delay produced by the unknown channel h(n)

Comment: @fibonatic We don't know the order of the unknown channel response h(n).I have varied the order of the adaptive filter to see the response but still the error which is the  difference between desired signal and estimated signal remains constant .

Comment: @Deepa not if the output of adaptive filter is earlier that d[n]. What you can do is to delay your input to adaptive filter alone (by zero padding) and try to match them.

Comment: @jithinrj But in my case, the adaptive filter output is already delayed than d(n)  by one sample.

Comment: @Deepa I wasn't aware of that. In that case your adaptive filter should adapt to the delay. If you could show us your program may be little more help. Or wait till some expert answers your question.

Comment: @jithinrj I am using matlab inbuilt function of nlms and the input sample is white noise generated using randn function in matlab.The desired signal is the data captured after passing the white noise through a speaker and capturing with mic

Comment: @jithinrj I have attached the matlab code for further clarification.

Comment: @Deepa I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I modified the code given here and was able to adapt the LMS filter with error tapering to zero. The only assumption I made is that (since I am not an audio expert and do not know how the channel from speaker to the microphone would look like), I assumed a 10 tap channel with only first 3 non-zero values (multi-path reflection from walls). OP is free to use a channel of his/her choice. Using this I generated 'actual_fb_path' by convolving white-noise with assumed channel. If I get access to 'actual_fb_path' it would be great. **I would request OP to modify this as per the system model to see if it adapts to the delay.**

```
clc
clear all
close all
training_input = rand(1,100);
h_actual = [0.8 0.3 0.05 zeros(1,7)]; %channel assumption
actual_fb_path = conv(training_input, h_actual);
d = actual_fb_path;
mu = 0.1;
%ha = lms(40,mu);
%[y,e] = filter(ha, training_input, d);
lms = dsp.LMSFilter;
lms.StepSize = mu;
lms.Length = 10;
[y,e]=lms([training_input zeros(1,9)]', d');
%subplot(2,1,1)
N=length(training_input) + length(h_actual)-1;
figure()
plot(1:N,d,'r',1:N,y,'b',1:N,e,'g')
title('System')
legend('Desired','Output','Error')
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried convolving the white noise with an impulse response similar to your's,I am getting error values going down to 0.However,the feedback samples obtained in the practical scenario(white noise passed through speaker), it fails to give the desired result.Since I can't attach excel sheet containing actual data samples here,its difficult to show the scenario.I will attach the matlab figure I have obtained.

Comment: @Deepa it may happen that the noise itself is high. Can you just sample the noise alone from speaker (without giving any input to it)? How does that look?

Comment: Did you meant the white noise which is given to the speaker

Comment: Not the white noise. Do not give any input to speaker.

Comment: The data samples obtained from the speaker is almost constant random values